# datetime picker mindate and maxdate

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I use this code for to set mindate and maxdate hour in datetimepicker :

```
oraDa.MinDate = DateTime.Parse("14:00");
oraDa.MaxDate = DateTime.Parse("22:00");`.
```

My problem is when I want to set another mindate and maxdate for another work shift:

```
oraDa.MinDate = DateTime.Parse("22:00");
oraDa.MaxDate = DateTime.Parse("6:00");.
```

The message error is

> mindate must be minor less than maxdate.

Any help please? thanks

Comment: Well I guess thats because 22:00 is after 6:00, try to think on another way to solve this.

Comment: for you which will be a possible solution?

Answer (score 2):

The problem ist that you get today as date when you parse a time. 
And today 22:00 is less than today 6:00.

You could avoid this problem when using this piece of code

```
oraDa.MinDate = DateTime.Parse("22:00");
oraDa.MaxDate = DateTime.Parse("6:00").AddDays(1);
```

For today you would get **MinDate = 13.06.2017 22:00** and **MaxDate = 14.06.2017 6:00**

Comment: thanks for reply! I use this solution, but when set maxdate expression, come show hour until 23.00...I don't know why...

Answer (score 1):

A DateTime variable (or property) is always composed by a date part and a time part. If you don't set the date part, it is assumed to be the today date, so your DateTime.Parse code produces the following results

```
13/06/2017 06:00 is lesser than 13/06/2017 22:00
```

So you are forced to put the full date and you don't need to parse a string for that.

```
oraDa.MinDate = DateTime.Today.AddHours(22);
oraDa.MaxDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).AddHours(6);
```